# Run three functions asynchronously and wait till the three functions get completed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

In the following function named `start` three functions are called successively. After all the functions are executed, the container function `start` is called again.

Is there any way, where I could run the three functions parallelly or asynchronously and when all the three get completed, the `start` method is called again.

```
function start(){
    resolveErrorQueue((err,data)=>{
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else{
                checkIfAlive((err,data) => {
                   if(err)
                       console.log(err);
                   else{
                      prepareServer((err,data) => {
                        if(err)
                            console.log(err);
                        else
                            start();
                      }); 
                   }                    
                });
            }               
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with user2263572's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41748917/2365824) that you should use promises. It's even simpler using ES6 [Promises](http://node.green/#Promise) that have been supported natively by Node.js since v4.7.1.

Here's a working example:

```js
function resolveErrorQueue(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("no errors in queue");
    }, 1000);
}

function checkIfAlive(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("server is alive");
    }, 999);
};

function prepareServer(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("server is prepared");
    }, 1001);
};

var counter = 0;
function start() {
    Promise.all([new Promise(resolveErrorQueue), new Promise(checkIfAlive), new Promise(prepareServer)]).then(values => {
        console.log(`${++counter}: ${values}`);
        start();
    });
}
start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is using a promise library.  For example, in Q you can use the q.all function

```
Q.all([getFromDisk(), getFromCloud()]).done(function (values) {
    assert(values[0] === values[1]); // values[0] is fromDisk and values[1] is fromCloud
});
```

If you want to do it without promises, you can create a global variable that is incremented each time an async function completes.  Then call your 3 async functions, and in the callback increment the global variable.  You can also store the return data globally if needed.

You can then use a while loop or setInterval to check if the 3 functions have all returned.

Answer (score 1):

Using [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/index.html) module's [parallel](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel):

```
async.parallel([resolveErrorQueue, checkIfAlive, prepareServer], (err, results) => {
  if (err)
    console.error(err);
  else
    start();
});
```

Since your methods seems to work with callback `async` module will fit well. If methods also support promises then that can also be done, e.g. using Bluebird [Promise.join](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) or Q.all (as mentioned by @user2263572).

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are after, but something like this, perhaps?

```
function start(){
    var leftToRun = 3;

    resolveErrorQueue((err,data)=>{
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else{
            if (--leftToRun === 0) { start(); }
        }
    });

    checkIfAlive((err,data) => {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else{
            if (--leftToRun === 0) { start(); }
        }
    });

    prepareServer((err,data) => {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            if (--leftToRun === 0) { start(); }
    }); 
}
```

It won't actually run in parallell, since Node only runs your code in one thread, but if the operations you call are asynchronous, the functions don't have to finish in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async.series()` method in nodejs. The `async` is a module which provide various method to execute asynchoronous method in `nodejs`.

**For example:**

```
async.series([function1,function2,function3],function(err,result{
if(err){
      // do here if error occured. 
  }
      console.log(result);
     // DO here what you want to do after function1, function2 and function3 completion. 
});


var function1 = function(cb){
     // do here in function1 
        cb(null,'ok');
  };

var function2 = function(cb){
    // do here in function2 
        cb(null,'ok');
  };

var function3 = function(cb){
   // do here in function3 
        cb(null,'ok');
  };
```

You can add any number of function as an arguments in `async.series()`.